# Shadow DOM/Web component styling in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, ionic4, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I'm trying to understand how and where ionic 4 is injecting the styling for the web components into the dom. I'm not interested in changing it via the CSS variables but I want to be able to inspect the component and see where the styling is coming from. For example on https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/alert/index.html?ionic:mode=ios

If you inspect the button:

[image: Ionic styled button]

I can see the stlying being applied but I can't see where all the styling is coming from, it's not in the css bundle, style tags on the page or directly on the element or applied to the shadow-root. Normally the host styling is part of the component e.g.

[image: styled web component]

So where is the :host styling being defined and how/where is it being injected into the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I know all the styles you apply to your component are usually set innerHTML. You already found the style tag which is the first tag after the component. This is super full with stylings as always thats why you usually see just a snippet. That depends on the browser but to see all the stylings you may have to do a double click into the stylings between the style tags.

[image]

Usually when I want to read something like this I copy it into my editor and take a look there:

[image]

As you can see all your stylings are defined there. Stenciljs also load some general stylings to make sure everything looks proper. These are instantiated into your head section:
[image]

Comment: Hi Christian, that's the kind of thing that I was expecting to see but when I inspect the page: https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/alert/index.html?ionic:mode=ios

And go to the button, in Chrome/Brave the style tag isn't visible to me. And if I attempt to select it (to see if there is one) I get null




document.querySelector('body > ion-app > ion-content > ion-button').shadowRoot.querySelector('style')
null

Is your screenshot from the same page? because I don't see the same.

Comment: Yes this screenshot is from your page but I use the latest Firefox. I just tried Chrome and can't see the style tag too. http://prntscr.com/ptujl1 - Since i don't use Chrome i can't say if that's the normal behavior but I don't think so... Seems like a bug in Chrome since the styles are rendered but no inline style is set.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in chrome. Since other none Ionic web components show the styling. Interestingly Safari shows the same as Firefox.

Comment: The Style tag and everything else is generated in JavaScript dynamically maybe Chrome has some trouble with this procedure in this specific case. You can try to use in the @component decorator of your tsx file to use "scoped:true" instead of "shadow:true" to check what happens than. But I would suggest to open a new Question like "Why chrome doesn't show up dynamically generated style tag" since firefox and safari clearly shows it up. Than maybe some Chrome pros can answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I think Ionic 4 is using: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets

Which is why the styling isn't visible directly in the DOM. Credit to Fraser for working this out.